# Python transform json

Tags: python, json

I have a text file with entries like this:

```
[
{
    "Exceptions": {
        "GUID": "028326A8206D44A736B45FE6125E59B2",
        "ExceptionName": "madrid,barcelona",
        "TargetHostname": "www.spain.com",
        "TargetName": "spain",
        "HasModule": true
    }
},

{
    "Exceptions": {
        "GUID": "028326A8206D44A736B45FE6125E59B2",
        "ExceptionName": "london,liverpool",
        "TargetHostname": "www.uk.com",
        "TargetName": "uk",
        "HasModule": true
    }
},

{
    "Exceptions": {
        "GUID": "028326A8206D44A736B45FE6125E59B2",
        "ExceptionName": "dublin,cork",
        "TargetHostname": "www.ireland.com",
        "TargetName": "ireland",
        "HasModule": true
    }
}
]
```

I would like a rule for each city, I need to modify this json.

I tried some things with python for, but I didn't get anything like that

I need a pyhton script that converts this input rule to the model below.
The expected result is, I would like the result to be like this:

So i need each city to give me a rule like that inside json.
Thank you all for your help.

I needed each rule of each country ... to stay within the specific json of the country.

example spain.json

```
[
{
"Exceptions": {
    "GUID": "028326A8206D44A736B45FE6125E59B2",
    "ExceptionName": "madrid",
    "TargetHostname": "www.spain.com",
    "TargetName": "spain",
    "HasModule": true
  }
 },
 {
"Exceptions": {
    "GUID": "028326A8206D44A736B45FE6125E59B2",
    "ExceptionName": "barcelona",
    "TargetHostname": "www.spain.com",
    "TargetName": "spain",
    "HasModule": true
  }
 }
]
```

example uk.json

```
[
{
"Exceptions": {
    "GUID": "028326A8206D44A736B45FE6125E59B2",
    "ExceptionName": "london",
    "TargetHostname": "www.uk.com",
    "TargetName": "uk",
    "HasModule": true
  }
 },
 {
"Exceptions": {
    "GUID": "028326A8206D44A736B45FE6125E59B2",
    "ExceptionName": "liverpool",
    "TargetHostname": "www.uk.com",
    "TargetName": "uk",
    "HasModule": true
  }
 }
]
```

You can help me with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import copy
import json
mylist = []
for e in a: #a is the original list.
    mylist = []
    for city in e["Exceptions"]["ExceptionName"].split(","):
        new = copy.deepcopy(e)
        new["Exceptions"]["ExceptionName"] = city
        mylist.append(new)
    with open(f"{new['Exceptions']['TargetName']}.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(mylist, f)
```

Comment: I ended up editing the post, can you help me, I needed each rule to be in a new file.

example spain.json

all the rules of spain.

uk.json all UK rules

ireland.json all ireland rules.

You can help me with that.

Comment: I noticed that I hadn't saved my post, I'm sorry, I just updated and thanks for the help.

Comment: I have updated my answer to write each one to a seperate file.

Comment: Hey. you are spectacular ... solves my problem ... thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help